# How to simplify emit changes using rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a collection of text:

```
public texts: TextCollection = <TextCollection>{};
```

And subject `public textPropertiesChanges$ = new ReplaySubject();` where I put `texts` changes.

There are a lot of places where `this.text` is changed, for example setting property or adding a new element, etc.

Problem is that after changes I need to `this.textPropertiesChanges$.next(this.texts);`.

It brings a dirty code.

How is it possible to improve it?

Comment: if you don't have to track changes just use BehaviorSubject which always give you the last value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encapsulate logic of changing text in some method like `setText(text)` which will do the action either it's calling `next` or setting/removing some field.

I suppose Your app is not big enough to introduce global/local store concept.